# How can I list all kubernetes nodes and sort by the nodes that have the most pods?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is there a --sort-by option that allows you to sort by nodes which have the greatest number of pods running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this way:

```
kubectl get nodes -o=custom-columns=Pods:.status.capacity.pods,NAME:metadata.name | sort -nr
```

or `kubectl get nodes --sort-by=.status.capacity.pods`

Comment: Thanks that first option works well, the last node IP is the one with the most pods on it.